# Подключение дополнительных камер к образу который использует ROS

Tags: navigation, python, quadcopter, rostopic

Всем привет. В ROS не разбираюсь. Столкнулся с проблемой подключения дополнительных камер на raspberry pi 4 с использованием образа clover_v0.23.img. Моя зада состоит в том, чтобы подключить камеру через USB, при этом к raspberry pi подключена ещё и стандартная камера. Камеру, которую подключаю через USB сама raspberry pi видит, но оптический потлк не выводиться с этой камеры. Без стандартной камеры raspberry pi, оптический поток с USB камеры вывщдиться хорошо. Помогите пожалуйста, чем сможете.

---

From Google translate:

> Hi all. I don't understand ROS. I encountered a problem connecting additional cameras on Raspberry pi 4 using the clover_v0.23.img image. My task is to connect the camera via USB, while a standard camera is also connected to the raspberry pi. The raspberry pi itself sees the camera that I connect via USB, but the optical ceiling is not output from this camera. Without a standard raspberry pi camera, the optical flow from the USB camera is good. Please help in any way you can.

Comment: Or [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: So the camera connected to the CSI shows no output. Are you sure that it is a ROS issue? What happens if you boot the Pi with Ubuntu or Raspbian OS? Does the camera connected to the CSI port work in that situation?

Comment: Таким образом, камера, подключенная к CSI, не показывает выходных данных. Вы уверены, что это проблема ROS? Что произойдет, если вы загрузите Pi с ОС Ubuntu или Raspbian? Работает ли в такой ситуации камера, подключенная к порту CSI?